# How to get access to reader monad with Generalized Auth in Servant

Tags: haskell, servant

I am trying to get access to my custom monad in the Generalized Auth Handler But i Haven't been able to solve the TypeErros I am getting. I've tried following along with the docs but I haven't been able to convert the examples over to my use case (this is probably because I lack a fully developed understanding of the type level machinery going on in the server). I have an auth situation which doesn't quite fit the Servant-Auth case. Here is the minimal server.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts      #-}

module Adapter.Servant.TodoAPI2 (todoApp) where

import ClassyPrelude hiding (Handler)
import Servant
import Servant.Server
import Servant.Server.Experimental.Auth (AuthHandler, AuthServerData,
                                         mkAuthHandler)
import Control.Monad.Except
import Domain.Types.AppT 
import Domain.Types.AppEnv
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger

readerToHandler :: AppEnv -> AppT a -> Handler a
readerToHandler env appt = do
  val <- liftIO $ runExceptT $ runReaderT (runAppT appt) env
  case val of
    Left e -> throwError e
    Right s -> return s 

type TodoAPI = "a" :> Get '[JSON] Int
          :<|> "b" :> Get '[JSON] Bool
          :<|> "c" :> Get '[JSON] Int
          :<|> "d" :> AuthProtect "JWT" :> Get '[JSON] Int

todoAPI :: Proxy TodoAPI
todoAPI = Proxy

todoServerT :: ServerT TodoAPI AppT
todoServerT = a 
         :<|> b 
         :<|> c 
         :<|> d 
  where
    a :: AppT Int
    a = return 1797

    b :: AppT Bool
    b = return True

    c :: AppT Int
    c = throwError $ (ServerError 500 "Failed Computation" "" [])

    d :: AuthUser -> AppT Int
    d au = do
      sec <- asks secret 
      liftIO $ print $ sec 
      return $ 1798

todoServer :: AppEnv -> Server TodoAPI
todoServer env = hoistServer todoAPI (readerToHandler env) todoServerT

todoApp :: AppEnv -> Application
todoApp env = serveWithContext todoAPI (genAuthServerContext env) (todoServer env)


data AuthUser = AuthUser 
  { auth_user_id :: Int64 
  , auth_user_email :: Text
  } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)


type instance AuthServerData (AuthProtect "JWT") = AuthUser

authHandler :: AppEnv -> AuthHandler Request (AuthUser)
authHandler env =
  let handler req =
        case lookup "Authorization" (requestHeaders req) of
          Nothing ->
            throwError (err401 {errBody = "Missing 'Authorization' header"})
          Just token -> do
            liftIO $ print $ secret env
            -- sec <- asks secret
            case (token == "HELLOWORLD") of
              False ->
                throwError (err401 {errBody = "Wrong 'Authorization' token"})
              -- True -> do
              True -> return $ AuthUser 1 "ethangardner@afito.com"
                -- return $ AuthUser 1 "ethangardner@afito.com"
  in mkAuthHandler handler

genAuthServerContext :: AppEnv -> Context (AuthHandler Request (AuthUser) ': '[])
genAuthServerContext env = (authHandler env) :. EmptyContext
```

If possible I would like to not pass my AppEnv to my handler and simply treat it as if it were just part of my Reader and use `asks`.

Below are my AppEnv and AppT.

```
module Domain.Types.AppEnv (AppEnv(..)) where

import ClassyPrelude hiding (Handler)
import Data.Pool
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple

data AppEnv = AppEnv 
 { pgEnv :: !(Pool Connection)
 , secret :: Text
 }
```

```
module Domain.Types.AppT (AppT(..)) where

import ClassyPrelude
import Servant.Server
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.Catch (MonadThrow)
import Domain.Types.AppEnv

newtype AppT a = AppT 
 { runAppT :: ReaderT AppEnv (ExceptT ServerError IO) a
 } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadReader AppEnv, MonadThrow, MonadError ServerError)
```

EDIT: Errors

Error:

```
    • No instance for (HasContextEntry
                         '[] (AuthHandler Request AuthUser))
        arising from a use of ‘hoistServer’
    • In the expression:
        hoistServer todoAPI (readerToHandler env) todoServerT
      In an equation for ‘todoServer’:
          todoServer env
            = hoistServer todoAPI (readerToHandler env) todoServerT
   |
55 | todoServer env = hoistServer todoAPI (readerToHandler env) todoServerT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hoistServer :: HasServer api '[] => Proxy api -> (forall x. m x -> n x) -> ServerT api m -> ServerT api n
```

You're calling `hoistServer` where `api ~ TodoAPI`, so we need to solve the constraint `HasServer TodoAPI '[]`. The relevant instance for the problem you're having is this one:

```
instance (HasServer api context, HasContextEntry context (AuthHandler Request (AuthServerData (AuthProtect tag)))) => HasServer (AuthProtect tag :> api :: Type) context
```

So now we need to solve the constraint `HasContextEntry context (AuthHandler Request (AuthServerData (AuthProtect tag)))`. `tag` there is `"JWT"`, so plug that in, then apply your `type instance`, and we get that we need to solve `HasContextEntry context (AuthHandler Request AuthUser)`.

The trouble is, what's `context` there? It's `'[]`. Well, that's not going to work. **To fix it, you need to use `hoistServerWithContext` instead of `hoistServer`, like this:**

```
todoServer env = hoistServerWithContext todoAPI (Proxy :: Proxy '[AuthHandler Request AuthUser]) (readerToHandler env) todoServerT
```

That has this type:

```
hoistServerWithContext :: HasServer api context => Proxy api -> Proxy context -> (forall x. m x -> n x) -> ServerT api m -> ServerT api n
```

So we get to solve `HasServer TodoAPI '[AuthHandler Request AuthUser]` instead, so now we can solve the `HasContextEntry` constraint, and it compiles fine.

Comment: Thank you this definitely solves the problem I was a bit thrown off by the `Context '[]` part of the error. Your explanation helps a lot and is very thorough thank you.

Comment: Hi Joseph! What would be the proper invocation when using `genericServerTWithContext`? :)

Comment: @Hécate Please ask that in a new question of its own.